# Is it possible, to use constraint object multiple times in SQL?

Tags: sql

I created a table with a string length check constraint. I have to use the same constraint on multiple tables. This check looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE Persons{
...
CONSTRAINT check_pesel CHECK (LEN(PESEL) = 11),
};
```

and now I want use check_pesel in multiple tables. If I just copy and paste this line, I'm getting error that object with this name already exists. So my question is, is it possible to use this object twice etc. ? This would look better than replacing the name with check_pesel2 etc.

Comment: The name needs to be unique, so do that however you wish, eg prefix with the table name `table1_check_pesel`, `table2_check_pesel`...

Comment: You can opt to an inline check kind of `PESEL varchar(11) not null CHECK (LEN(PESEL) = 11)`  and DBMS will autogenerate the name of the constraint.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It would be helpful I guess if there would be option to use multiple times the same constraint. In this case I don't see any sense to use names for it (maybe for extensive conditions) but it's not my question.

Comment: For production databases it's recommended to name all constraints. Otherwise it's difficult to alter or remove constraints when you don't have access to prod and need to send a SQL script to Operations.